# scipy solve_ivp event gives result but does not terminate the simulation

Tags: python, events, scipy, numerical-integration

I am experiencing some problems with events in scipy solve_ivp.
The event is triggered, and I can get the event times from the results, but somehow the simulation is not terminated and result.status does not change.
Maybe someone can give me some pointers what to try or has experienced the same problem and found a solution?

result.t_events: `[array([11.77036535, 13.83038927])]`

result.status: `0`

```
def tester(t, y, cond1, cond2):
    if y[3] > cond1 and max(y) > cond2:
        val = cond2 - max(y)
    else:
        val = 1
    return val

tester.terminal = True
tester.direction = -1

result = solve_ivp(fun = lambda t, y: func(t,y, para_dict), t_span = tspan, y0 = InitialValues, method = "RK45", dense_output = True, events = lambda t, y: tester(t, y, cond1, cond2)) 

print(result.t_events)
print(result.status)
```

Comment: You haven't shown the import statements, and you haven't defined `func`, `para_dict`, `tspan`, etc.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be better. I hoped someone would spot the error immediately, since the other components should not really affect the event, especially since it is recorded already and just the status is not changing.

Comment: I have a suspicion of what the error is, but I can't run your code, so I can't confirm it, and I don't want to waste time guessing.  It really is helpful to have a *minimal* example that we can run to reproduce the problem.